# ignore alphabets while looping through cells

Tags: vba, excel

From my GUI , I enter numbers like this: 9811,7841 which will be sent to my macro. My macro is:

```
sub highlight(fm as variant)
dim sh as worksheet
Dim i As Integer
dim j as integer
dim k As Long
Dim rn As Range
din number() as integer
If phm <> 0 Then

phm = Split(phm, ",")
ReDim number(LBound(phm) To UBound(phm)) As Integer

Set sh = w.Worksheets("Sheet1")
sh.Select
Cells.Find("Type").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
 Set rn = sh.UsedRange
 k = rn.Rows.Count + rn.Row - 1

For i = 1 To k
For j = LBound(number) To UBound(number)

number(j) = CInt(phm(j))

If ActiveCell.Value = number(j) Or IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
Else
Selection.Interior.Color = vbGreen
Exit For
End If


Next j
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'moves activecell down one row.
Next i


End If
ActiveWorkbook.Save


End Sub
```

I would like to modify my code in such that alphabets are ignored if present in any cell.In the below case, cell3 and cell 5 should be highlighted as my "fm" contains 9811,7841 so cell 1,2,4 are valid.Alphabets should be ignored if any while checking the cells.

```
Sheet1
cell 1: 9811
cell 2: hello 9811
cell 3: 3428
cell 4: hello 7841
cell 5:hello 2545
```

Comment: Why don't you refrain user from entering alphabet into the cells? [Check this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11133771/1389394)

Comment: No, i cannot do that :/

Comment: Duplicate of [Ignore alphabets in a cell, only numbers should be checked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30542051/ignore-alphabets-in-a-cell-only-numbers-should-be-checked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is with a regular expression. Add a reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions, then just do a pattern replacement:

```
Private Function StripNonNumerics(inValue As String) As String

    Dim regex As New RegExp
    With regex
        .Pattern = "\D"
        .Global = True
        StripNonNumerics = .Replace(inValue, vbNullString)
    End With

End Function
```

Note that there'll be less overhead if you incorporate this into your sub or make the regex a global (that way you don't have to repeatedly create the RegExp object.

Comment: Change `If ActiveCell.Value = number(j)` to `If Val(StripNonNumerics(ActiveCell.Value)) = number(j)`

Comment: It throws me this error "user defined type not defined"

Comment: You need to add the reference. Tools -> References... then check Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the VBA function "Instr"

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Assuming that phm is your array that contains one number of fm in every cell:

you need to change your line

```
 If ActiveCell.Value = number(j) Or IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
```

to

```
 If Instr(ActiveCell.Value,number(j)) > 0 Or IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
```

Comment: All cells are highlighted :/